# Диаграмма состояний UML (видеоплеер)

Tags: uml

Требуется выделить два объекта (в контексте UML) для видеоплеера на ПК, для которых есть не менее пяти состояний.

На мой взгляд (если я правильно выделил объект), один из возможных объектов - это *playback* с состояниями ожидание-открытие-воспроизведение-пауза-стоп.

Какой еще объект можно выделить?

Спасибо за помощь!

P.S. Возможно не так понимаю задание и роюсь не там, вот текст задания из методички

> "Выбрать два объекта в рамках выбранной предметной области (в
> контексте диаграммы состояний UML), для которых характерны наличие
> нескольких (не менее пяти) состояний на разных стадиях работы
> разрабатываемого программного продукта (ПП) и переходов между ними."

Comment: Получилось разобраться? Вопрос все еще актуален?

Comment: Да, ещё актуально